# select() a textarea within an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, textarea

I have a textarea within an iframe.  I want to select the textarea text with an onclick event in JavaScript.

Example:

```
I have an iframe.

The inner content of the iframe is this:
<textarea id="textarea" disabled onclick="selectthis()">
"content of textarea"
</textarea>
```

I want to select the text so the user can copy it:

```
I put this at the head of my page:

function selectthis() {
   document.getElementById('textarea').select();
}
```

But when I click on the textarea, it's not selected.

Comment: I think you have to focus it first.

Comment: document.getElementById('textarea') At least you must rectify misspelled methods name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You typed `getElementById` wrong.

---

Change `getelementById` to `getElementById`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

[image] http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ArGhg/

**Plus,**

```
<textarea id="textarea" onclick="selectthis">  <!--Nope-->
<textarea id="textarea" onclick="selectthis();">  <!--Yup!-->
```

---

### UPDATE

I see what you did there. You can not select text within a *disabled* `<textarea>`.
See http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ArGhg/2/

According to Francisc's comment, using `readonly` will solve the problem.
See http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ArGhg/3/

Comment: That `Yup` should also be a `Nope` though.

Comment: @Francisc - Shouldn't really use inline `onclick`, but it is still correct.

Comment: @PitaJ - See update. You can't select text with in a disabled `textarea`.

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
document.getElementById('textarea').select();
```

Functions are case-sensitive in Javascript, so make sure you capitalize everything properly (I capitalized the `e` of `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `selectthis` probably generates an ecception since it can't find any element with `textarea` as id. The problem is that you use `document.getElementById` (I fixed the typo), but the textarea doesn't belong to `document`.
You have to access to the iframe own document object, usually with something like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
var ifrDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
var textarea = ifrDoc.getElementById("textarea");
textarea.select();
```

Note: in IE8 you have to specify a doctype, while in earlier versions you can use `iframe.contentWindow.document` instead.